# Can I disable my firebase database for a part of time?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For exemple: I wish to disable the database from 00:00AM to 05:00AM, or anytime on Saturday or Sunday.

I don't want to allow users to Interact with the database. (write or listen to the updates)

Can I do it using the firebase structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve part of it with database rules, the other part would require a cron-job/scheduled task to toggle a record in the database.

Using Firebase Bolt Rules [(Read More)](https://github.com/firebase/bolt) you could create a function `isOnline()`

```
function isOnline() {
  return prior(root.config.isOnline) == true
}
```

The rule will check `/config/isOnline: boolean` and is expecting `true` if you want users to `write` and `false` if you want to block writing.

In all your database rules you would need to reference this function.

```
path /somePath {
  write() { isOnline() }
}
```

You could combine these with other rules such as user validation

```
function isUser(uid) {
  return auth != null && uid == auth.uid
}

path /someOtherPath {
   path /{uid} {
     write() { isUser(uid) && isOnline()
   }
}
```

You could then setup a cron-job/scheduled task to update the `/config/isOnline` property on 00:00AM and 05:00AM on Saturday / Sunday.

On Saturday & Sunday @ 00:00AM set `/config/isOnline = false`.

On Saturday & Sunday @ 05:00AM set `/config/isOnline = true`.